# Convert columns to the same data types to use in a join

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to join two tables but the columns being used are two different data types, table#1 = float and table#2 = varchar(8).

```
table#1 examples:
5585
985
445566
null

table#2 examples:
005585
000985
445566
```

In these examples, I get data for only row 445566

How do I cast/convert??? the columns so that all the rows matching return data

Comment: I don't really understand why you'd need to cast/convert. FLOATs have higher precedence than VARCHARs so VARCHARs should automatically be converted to FLOATs on joins. Unless I'm misunderstanding something. EDIT: A quick test in SQL shows I have no issues with a simple join on '005585' as a varchar joined with 5585 as a float.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
CAST('445566' AS FLOAT) = 445566
```

Comment: I should have clarified...I just provided 4 examples - the tables have thousands of rows of numerical data and instead of isolating one row, I was looking for a solution that would capture all the rows

Comment: This is how you `CAST` a type to another one, use it where you need, in this case in the condition of the `JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @Table1 table (SomeField1 float)
Insert Into @Table1 values (5585),(985),(445566),(null)

Declare @Table2 table (SomeField2 varchar(8))
Insert Into @Table2  values ('005585'),('000985'),('445566')


Select A.SomeField1
      ,B.SomeField2
 From @Table1 A
 Join @Table2 B 
   on cast(A.SomeField1 as int) = cast(B.SomeField2 as int)
```

Returns

```
SomeField1  SomeField2
5585        005585
985         000985
445566      445566
```

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on your exact join criteria. Generally, it is easier and safer to convert from a numeric type to varchar than vice versa, so you could do something like:

```
SELECT stuff FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON Convert(varchar(8),table1.field) = table2.field
```